# Stopped sync of photo's with iTunes, iPhone still claims little storage is used due to sync

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos.app

I recently stopped the synchronisation of photo's with iTunes on my iPhone. My iPhone removed all photo's it was still showing thanks to this synchronisation, but it still claims some storage is used due to synchronisation of photo's with iTunes.

I'm talking about 0.7 kB. I know it's not much, but nevertheless I'm wondering what it is used for.

Answer (score 1):

While I am unsure of the EXACT details of what may be left in that 0.7KB I  know your phone saves information about what computer it connects to so it knows it can trust it for syncing files, updating software, backing up, and so on. Along with information about what you do and do not want to be synced on the phone. All of that information is still needed whether you sync everything or nothing but would take up a very tiny amount of space, as you can see.